# how to compare two data.frames by column and ignore order of elements in each column

Tags: r, compare

I have two data.frames `a` and `b` and would like to compare column by column with the package `compare` which has a nice function to ignore order and transform only columns, it fails to detect columns with same elements but in different order

```
compare(a,b,ignoreOrder=TRUE,colsOnly=TRUE)
```

However when I compare column individually I get the wright answer. I am forced to check col by col with a lapply but then the result is not easily manageable as saving the output of compare directly.

```
b
   PFT             NAME HGT_MIN      DBH   BLEAF_MIN   BROOT_MIN BSAPWOOD_MIN  BALIVE_MIN   BDEAD_MIN  BLEAF_BL
1    1         C4_grass    0.50 0.121182 0.010073600 0.010073600  2.93168e-05 0.020176500 0.00000e+00 0.0100736
2    2   Early_tropical    0.50 0.121182 0.045331200 0.045331200  5.61608e-05 0.090718600 8.32140e-04 5.5130100
3    3     Mid_tropical    0.50 0.121182 0.026695100 0.026695100  5.48205e-05 0.053444900 4.90038e-04 5.6997500
4    4    Late_tropical    0.50 0.121182 0.035761300 0.035761300  5.33890e-05 0.071576000 6.56466e-04 8.0646600

a
   PFT             NAME HGT_MIN      DBH   BLEAF_MIN   BROOT_MIN BSAPWOOD_MIN  BALIVE_MIN   BDEAD_MIN  BLEAF_BL
1    1         C4_grass    0.50 0.121182 0.010073600 0.010073600  2.93168e-05 0.020176500 0.00000e+00 0.0100736
2    2   Early_tropical    0.50 0.121182 0.026695100 0.026695100  5.48205e-05 0.053444900 4.90038e-04 5.6997500
3    3     Mid_tropical    0.50 0.121182 0.035761300 0.035761300  5.33890e-05 0.071576000 6.56466e-04 8.0646600
4    4    Late_tropical    0.50 0.121182 0.045331200 0.045331200  5.61608e-05 0.090718600 8.32140e-04 5.5130100
```

Comment: please provide a minimally reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I appreciate this is an old question but I think `data.table` as a neat solution with [`all.equal`](https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.cube/library/data.table/html/all.equal.data.table.html):

```
> a <- data.frame(one=1:5,
+                 two=c("a","b","c","d","e"))
> b <- data.frame(one=c(5,4,3,2,1),
+                 two=c("e","d","c","b","a"))
> 
> a
  one two
1   1   a
2   2   b
3   3   c
4   4   d
5   5   e
> b
  one two
1   5   e
2   4   d
3   3   c
4   2   b
5   1   a
> #all.equal will give out as the row ordering is different
> all.equal(a,b)
[1] "Component “one”: Mean relative difference: 1" "Component “two”: 4 string mismatches"        
> 
> #convert to a data.frame data.table
> a_dt <- data.table::setDT(a)
> b_dt <- data.table::setDT(b)
> 
> a_dt
   one two
1:   1   a
2:   2   b
3:   3   c
4:   4   d
5:   5   e
> b_dt
   one two
1:   5   e
2:   4   d
3:   3   c
4:   2   b
5:   1   a
> 
> #again check if all equal will still fail because of ordering
> all.equal(a_dt,b_dt)
[1] "Column 'one': Mean relative difference: 1"
> 
> 
> #lastly ignore row order
> all.equal(a_dt,b_dt,ignore.row.order = TRUE)
[1] TRUE
```

You can also get `all.equal` to ignore other things like column order. It is a neat function definitely worth checking out!

Comment: Thanks. In general I use `dplyr` but your solution with `data.table ` is the only one simple and reliable for datas from Relational Database Management System where order of columns and rows don't matter. It's why it's a good answer for datas from RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
b <- read.table(text="row PFT             NAME HGT_MIN      DBH   BLEAF_MIN   BROOT_MIN BSAPWOOD_MIN  BALIVE_MIN   BDEAD_MIN  BLEAF_BL
1    1         C4_grass    0.50 0.121182 0.010073600 0.010073600  2.93168e-05 0.020176500 0.00000e+00 0.0100736
                2    2   Early_tropical    0.50 0.121182 0.045331200 0.045331200  5.61608e-05 0.090718600 8.32140e-04 5.5130100
                3    3     Mid_tropical    0.50 0.121182 0.026695100 0.026695100  5.48205e-05 0.053444900 4.90038e-04 5.6997500
                4    4    Late_tropical    0.50 0.121182 0.035761300 0.035761300  5.33890e-05 0.071576000 6.56466e-04 8.0646600",header=T)[,-1]

a <- read.table(text="row PFT             NAME HGT_MIN      DBH   BLEAF_MIN   BROOT_MIN BSAPWOOD_MIN  BALIVE_MIN   BDEAD_MIN  BLEAF_BL
1    1         C4_grass    0.50 0.121182 0.010073600 0.010073600  2.93168e-05 0.020176500 0.00000e+00 0.0100736
                2    2   Early_tropical    0.50 0.121182 0.026695100 0.026695100  5.48205e-05 0.053444900 4.90038e-04 5.6997500
                3    3     Mid_tropical    0.50 0.121182 0.035761300 0.035761300  5.33890e-05 0.071576000 6.56466e-04 8.0646600
                4    4    Late_tropical    0.50 0.121182 0.045331200 0.045331200  5.61608e-05 0.090718600 8.32140e-04 5.5130100",header=T)[,-1]

compare <- data.frame(sapply(1:ncol(a), function(x){a[,x]==b[,x]}))
names(compare) <- names(a)
colSums(!compare)
```

If the result has any column with a number more than zero, it would imply there are mismatches.